# Highlight encrypted document using Embedded Solr

Tags: encryption, solr, highlight

I have a unique requirement to highlight search terms on an encrypted solr document. The field to be highlighted is stored as encrypted data (but indexed as plain text). To show the search results to user it is decrypted on the client side.

To highlight search terms, I'm planning to use embedded solr to reindex the result document on client (with same schema and solrconfig) in memory using RamDirectoryFactory. Typical data size to be highlighted would be few hundred kbs. Very few could be in MB range.

Since embedded solr also needs creation of core directory, would the above solution work in a multi threaded environment? Although index is in memory but the physical core/config directory would possibly be shared due to multithreaded client. I am creating embedded solr server and returning highlight results in method scope only.

Comment: Are you going to create separate instance of embedded solr for each search result? By default only one process can write into the index directory with native lock type. So how are you going to make is multi threaded?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. After giving it some thought, now I am creating unique solr home/core directory for each highlight request so that it would not need synchronization code. I delete the temp solr home after each request finishes.  My original question was if I use *RAMDirectoryFactory* does solr  keep the index completely in memory and whether it creates the in-memory index per thread or is it shared..

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** You can use it. The `solr.RAMDirectoryFactory`, is memory based, not persistent. The whole index will be stored in the RAM memory. It fits your requirement as you don't to store the indexes and planning to create temporary setup for each search request.